Printing a chart that has labels and textbox added to it
I am trying to print my chart I have created. That part I have been able to do no problem. The issues lie with getting it to print off the labels I have added along with a user input text box field. I have searched the internet far and wide but have not noticed where anyone has had a similar issue. My current code is as follows:
Private Sub btnPrintSpectrum_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click 
    chart1.Printing.PrintDocument = New Printing.PrintDocument()
    AddHandler Chart1.Printing.PrintDocument.PrintPage, AdressOf Chart_PrintPage
Chart1.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
Chart1.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(0, 1, 1 , 1)
Chart1.Printing.PrintPreview()
End Sub 

Private Sub Chart_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal ev As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim ChartPostion As Rectangle = New Rectangle(ev.MarginBounds.X, ev.MarginBounds.Y, ev.MarginBounds.Width, ev.MarginBounds.Height)
    Chart1.Printing.PrintPaint(ev.graphics,ChartPosition)
End Sub 


Please review and edit your code. Your btnPrintSpectrum_Click has no End Sub. Moreover, does it even compile? The lines with AddHandler seem nonsensical to me.

Ok I have corrected it I have to retype everything over the computer I code on does not have internet access.
